# Jquery ajax request fails with empty error message

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, error-handling, request

The following ajax request fails with empty error message:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: loginUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify({login : u, password : p}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
      console.log("========================== succes ==========================");
      //Do work
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("========================== fail ==========================");
      console.log(xhr.responseText+"---"+xhr+"---"+xhr.status+"---"+xhr+"---"+thrownError);
      console.log(arguments)
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = JSON.parse(errMsg.responseText).error+" "+errMsg.status;
    }
  });
```

The output of console.log in on error is as follows:

```
 First log:    ---[object Object]---0---[object Object]---
 Second log:   [Object, "error", ""]
```

This only happens when deployed on remote server with ssl certificates. It works fine locally. The backend is a ruby app. When testing on remote server the request doesn't show up in the ruby console. It's like it's never sent. 
Is the request correct?  It's impossible to debug right now because of the empty error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses ssl (has `https://`), then `http` requests won't be sent due to security concerns. Make sure your `loginUrl` is a `https` and it should be working fine.

Comment: LoginUrl is https. Still doesn't work. I get error with empty error message.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on other environment (staging instead of dev)  and it works fine. I think there is something wrong with the certificates on dev, but I'm not sure what exactly.